# Why unit tests for App.ts don't work? How fix unit tests for routes in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I tried to write unit tests for App.ts but nothing worked. I am using the testing-library/react.

Here is my App.ts file:

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";
import  GlobalStyle  from "../styles/globalStyle";
import theme from "../styles/theme";
import Loader from "../components/Loader/Loader";

const NotFoundPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/notFoundPage/NotFoundPage"));
const CourseDetailsPage = lazy(
  () => import("../pages/courseDetailsPage/CourseDetailsPage")
);
const CoursesPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/coursesPage/CoursesPage"));

 const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme as DefaultTheme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Suspense fallback={(<Loader />) as React.ReactNode}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<CoursesPage  />} />
          <Route path="/:id" element={<CourseDetailsPage />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I wrote some tests for the App but have errors.

I tried to write tests for this component, but the tests did not work. I have these errors:

1. ● App › renders NotFoundPage component for unknown routes

   expect(received).toBeInTheDocument()

   received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
   Received has value: null

```
      53 |     );
      54 |
    > 55 |     expect(screen.queryByTestId("not-found")).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                                               ^
      56 |   });
      57 | });
```

2. ● App › renders CourseDetailsPage component for '/:id' route

   TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="course-details"]
3. ● App › renders CoursesPage component for '/' route

   Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="courses"]

Here are my tests:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import theme from "../src/styles/theme";
import App from "../src/components/App";
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

jest.mock("../src/pages/notFoundPage/NotFoundPage", () => () => (
  <div data-testid="not-found" />
));
jest.mock("../src/pages/courseDetailsPage/CourseDetailsPage", () => () => (
  <div data-testid="course-details" />
));
jest.mock("../src/pages/coursesPage/CoursesPage", () => () => (
  <div data-testid="courses" />
));

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders CoursesPage component for '/' route", async () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    await screen
      .findByTestId("courses")
      .then((element) => expect(element).toBeInTheDocument());
  });

  it("renders CourseDetailsPage component for '/:id' route", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/123"]}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByTestId("course-details")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("renders NotFoundPage component for unknown routes", () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/unknown"]}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.queryByTestId("not-found")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```